# Como refrescar fullcalendar y marcar la fecha a que ya esta validada

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

tengo un codigo en angular donde muestra un formulario al dar click a la fecha en el fullcalendar pero al darle click me aparece que aun no esta la fecha, necesito darle espacio para que verifique que esta la fecha. y no se como hacer para que se marque agregada al seleccionarla sin darle ese espacio.

Y la segunda duda es que no me aparece el evento, a menos que refresque la pagina y ya intente y no me queda, busque varias maneras de refrescar y ya jalando el get en mi codigo de angular aun siguen sin mostrarse los eventos, si no refresco toda la pagina, espero me puedan ayudar

Aqui se muestra en la iamgene el error al darle click a la imagen. no me valida la fecha hasta que doy enter.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
codigo de angular para formulario

.list-group.animated.zoomIn                                     
    a.list-group-item.active.main-color-bg.obj-trans(href='')     
         //--Se agrega para el formulario del calendario 28-11-2020 
        button.close(type='button',data-toggle='pill', href='#pills-home', role='tab', aria-controls='pills-home',
                    aria-selected='true',ng-click='lista = true; tabla=false; registro= false') ×
        span.i.fa.fa-pencil-alt
        |  Agendar horario
    form.form-horizontal(name='myFormReg', novalidate='',autocomplete="off")
                
                .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-heading
                        h3.panel-title Agenda
                        button(onclick="calendario()") Calendario          
                    br
                    .panel-body
                        form.form-horizontal(name='myFormReg', novalidate='')  
                        
                         #calendar 
                         #refresh
    #fullcalendar
    #visualizar.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel', data-backdrop='static')
      .modal-dialog(role='document')
        .modal-content
          .modal-header
          
            button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close')
              span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
            h4.modal-title.text-center Datos del Evento
           
           .modal-body
            dl.dl-horizontal
              dt Titulo de Evento
              dd#title
              dt Inicio de Evento
              dd#start
              dt Fin de Evento
              dd#end
              dt Descipcion
              dd#descripcion
       
       -if (user.rol=== "secretaria")
    #cadastrar.modal.fade(tabindex='-1', role='dialog', aria-labelledby='exampleModalLabel', data-backdrop='static')
      .modal-dialog(role='document')
        .modal-content
          .modal-header
            button.close(type='button', data-dismiss='modal', aria-label='Close')
              span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
            h4.modal-title.text-center Registrar Evento
          .modal-body
            form.form-horizontal(method='POST')
              .form-group
              label.col-md-3.control-label Tesis
              .col-md-8.inputGroupContainer
                  .input-group
                      span.input-group-addon
                          span.i.fa.fa-book
                      .inputGroupContainer
                              select#title.btn.btn-default.col-md-8(name="tesis", ng-model='newCalendario.tesis',ng-init="tesis", ng-options='x.titulo for x in datos')
                                  option(style='display:none', value='') elige tesis ....    
                              span.input-group-text(style='color:red', ng-show='myFormReg.tesis.$invalid && myFormReg.tesis.$touched' )
                                  span(ng-show='myFormReg.tesis.$error.required')     
                                      | ingresa tesis.
                 br
              .form-group
              label.col-md-3.control-label Fecha
              .col-md-8.inputGroupContainer
                  .input-group
                      span.input-group-addon
                          span.i.fa.fa-calendar-alt
                      input#start.form-control(type='text', name='fecha', onkeypress='Data(event, this)', ng-model='newCalendario.fecha', placeholder='yyyy-MM-dd', required)
                                     
                  span(style='color:red', ng-show='myFormReg.fecha.$invalid || myFormReg.fecha.$touched')
                      span(ng-show='myFormReg.fecha.$error.required') ingresa fecha.
                      span(ng-show='myFormReg.fecha.$error.max') error fecha no valida!.
                      span(ng-show='myFormReg.fecha.$error.date') fecha no valida! 
                br
              .form-group
              label.col-md-3.control-label Hora
              .col-md-8.inputGroupContainer
                  .input-group
                      span.input-group-addon
                          span.i.fa.fa-calendar-alt
                      select#end.btn.btn-default(type='text', name='horario', onkeypress='Hora(event, this)', ng-model='newCalendario.hora', ng-options="x for x in horario", required)
                          option(style='display:none', value='') Elige un horario            
                  
                br
              .form-group
              label.col-md-4.control-label Lugar:
              .col-md-7.inputGroupContainer
                  .input-group
                      span.input-group-addon
                           span.i.fas.fa-map-marker-alt
                      select#descripcion.btn.btn-default(type='text', name='lugar', ng-model='newCalendario.lugar', ng-options="x for x in descripcion", required)
                          option(style='display:none', value='') Elige un auditorio  
                      br
              .form-group
                .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
                 .form-group
                 button.btn.btn-success(type='submit', ng-click='saveCalendario();',data-dismiss='modal', 
                            ng-disabled=`myFormReg.tesis.$invalid || myFormReg.hora.$invalid || myFormReg.fecha.$invalid || myFormReg.lugar.$invalid`)
                            span.i.fas.fa-check
                            |  Registrar
```

el codigo del fullcalendar

```
script.
  $(function() {
    //- var eventos = $('#eventosaqui').text();
    });
    function calendario(){
    var eventos =$('#eventosaqui').text();
    eventos = JSON.parse(eventos);
    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      locale:'es',
      weekends: false,
    header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    
    defaultDate: Date(),
    navLinks: true, 
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, 
    allDaySlot: false,
    weekend: true,
    minTime: '10:00:00',
    maxTime: '17:00:00',
    //--slotDuration: '03:00:00',
    //--slotLabelInterval : '03:00:00',
    
    businessHours: {
    start: '10:00', // hora final
    end: '17:00', // hora inicial
    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] // dias de semana, 0=Domingo
    },
    
    // crear nuevos eventos
    eventClick: function(event) {
    $('#visualizar #id').text(event.id);
    $('#visualizar #title').text(event.title);
    $('#visualizar #start').text(event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
    $('#visualizar #end').text(event.end.format('HH:mm:ss'));
    $('#visualizar #descripcion').text(event.descripcion);
    $('#visualizar').modal('show');
    return false;
    
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    //--$('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
    //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    //--$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', events);
    //--$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);         
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    //$('#refresh').on('click', function(){
    //$("#calendar").refetchEvents();
    //});
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    },
  
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end){
    // leemos las fechas de inicio de evento y hoy
    var check = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    // si el inicio de evento ocurre hoy o en el futuro mostramos el modal
    if (check >= today) {
    $('#cadastrar #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $('#cadastrar #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $('#cadastrar').modal('show');
    }
    // si no, mostramos una alerta de error
    else {
        alert("No se pueden crear eventos en el pasado!");
    }
    },
    buttonText: {
    prev: "Ant",
    next: "Sig",
    today: "Hoy",
    month: "Mes",
    week: "Semana",
    day: "Día",
    list: "Agenda"
    },
    weekText: "Sm",
    allDayText: "Todo el día",
    moreLinkText: "más",
    noEventsText: "No hay eventos para mostrar",
    
    events: eventos,
    
    });
    //calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    //--$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', events);
    //--$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', events);         
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
    //$('#refresh').on('click', function(){
    //$("#calendar").refetchEvents();
    //});
    //$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    //--cambiar color 
    $('.modal-body').attr('style','background-color:white');
    $('.fc-center h2').attr('style','color:black');
    }
    
    //Mascara para o campo data e hora
    function Data(evento, objeto){
    var keypress=(window.event)?event.keyCode:evento.which;
    campo = eval (objeto);
    if (campo.value == '00-00-0000'){
    campo.value=""
    }
    caracteres = '0123456789';
    separacao1 = '-';
    separacao2 = ' ';
    }
    function Hora(evento, objeto){
    var keypress=(window.event)?event.keyCode:evento.which;
    campo = eval (objeto);
    if (campo.value == '00:00:00'){
    campo.value=""
    }
    caracteres = '0123456789';
    separacao2 = ' ';
    separacao3 = ':';
    
    }
```